# How to start filtering only when the length of querytext is equal to 2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

How can I be able to start filtering only when the querytext's length is equal to 2?

I have this code and I do not know how to start filtering only when querytext.length >=2

```
<input type="search" ng-model="querytext">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in filteredList | filter:querytext>{{value.Name}}</li>
</ul>
$scope.filteredList =[{Id:1,Name:"Soul"},{Id:2,Name:"Croft"}];
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `ng-minlength="2"` to `<input>` element.

```
<input type="search" ng-model="querytext" ng-minlength="2" />
<!--                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Daiwei, here is what I did:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="querytext" ng-minlength="2">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="value in filteredList | filter:querytext>{{value.Name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and it works!Thanks!