# How to load data only if something typed in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have:

```
<input type="search" name="" placeholder="Search" class="inputsearchform" ng-model="search"/> 

<tr class="rowR" ng-repeat="data in loaded | filter:{song_name: search}">
```

Is it possible to load data only if I type 4 or more chars in input? I wrote the `inputChange` function, but I don't know how to call it from attribute of `tr`.

```
app.controller('main_control',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.inputChange = function(){
        if($(".inputsearchform").val().length > 3){
            $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
                $scope.loaded=data; 
            });
        }
    }       
});
```

Or maybe it will be better solution to load data when the page is loading but not to show it to the user, because it has 10000 items. And then search and show results only after typing 4 chars. How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use ngChange: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

You can add it to the input

```
<input ng-change="inputChange()" ... />
```

You could also change your inputChange function to check that $scope.search.length instead of using $(".inputsearchform").val().length.

```
if($scope.search.length > 3 && !$scope.loaded){...
```

Comment: Just to add a bit to why the OP shouldn't be using jQuery in the controller: the idea with Angular is to have the template be smart and render based on data changes (this is called being "declarative"). You don't want to be interjecting jQuery into the picture and trying to imperatively manipulate the DOM, as this could interfere with data changes elsewhere in your controller.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but not at all. I tried to type 5 chars and it searches well. Then I cleared input and typed 1 char. It shouldn't search but it does.

Comment: Add another condition to the if statement so that if the data has already been loaded it won't look again. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MatthewClise This condition didn't help. I mean I need to begin searching only if I type 4 chars. Maybe I should add function to `tr`?

Comment: Maybe try if($scope.search.length === 4)?

Comment: @MatthewClise No, I understood about loading data, your answer is clear, it helped. I'm asking about another thing, about beginning searching only if length > 3. If you could help it would be really great!

Comment: ng-minlength
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012036/how-to-start-filtering-only-when-the-length-of-querytext-is-equal-to-2

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-change="inputChange()"` to the input.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow Matthew's answer

drop jquery and use angular.

```
app.controller('main_control',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.inputChange = function(){
        if($scope.search.length > 4){
            $http.get("http://localhost:7001/load").success(function(data){
                $scope.loaded=data; 
            });
        }
    }       
});
```