# Apply filter only when the input is greater than 3 characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

How can I get the results of a ng-repeat by applying a filter of an input only when it is greater than 3 (or N) characters?

I've tried the following (**filter: input.lenght > 3**):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input" placeholder="Search">

<li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter: input.lenght > 3">
  {{ detail.name }}
</li>
```

But it does not work. How can I do what I want? Greetings friends.

Solution:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="input" ng-minlength="3" placeholder="Search">
```

Answer (score 6):

use ternary operation for the filter like this

`<li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter: (input.length > 3)? input : ''">`

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.details = [{"name":"ssss"},{"name":"aaaa"},{"name":"cccc"}]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <input type="text" ng-model="input" placeholder="Search">

<li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter: (input.length > 3)? input : ''">
  {{ detail.name }}
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, friend, I had already found the solution in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012036/how-to-start-filtering-only-when-the-length-of-querytext-is-equal-to-2

Comment: This option was better for me than `ng-minlength` since it didn't inject form validation classes which made red borders on my inputs (poor UX for users to immediately feel like they did something wrong in a typeahead).